# How to replace a value within an array of embedded document in MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Please help me, I am very new to MongoDB (Just a week passed and I am liking it), I am stuck on manipulating a field within an array of embedded documents. I want to use aggregation (not update).

Below is a collection of 2 documents:

- On each document, I want to replace the '**content**' of each **lecture** with '000' if the lecture's **preview** is false, otherwise, I want to keep the original value.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Level 1",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "Horizontal zero administration moratorium",
        "lectures": [
          {
            "title": "Balanced exuding adapter",
            "content": "758050245",
            "preview": true
          },
          {
            "title": "Versatile mission-critical forecast",
            "content": "758050246",
            "preview": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Level 2",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "Inverse systemic solution",
        "lectures": [
          {
            "title": "Phased executive function",
            "content": "758050247",
            "preview": false
          },
          {
            "title": "Stand-alone object-oriented intranet",
            "content": "758050248",
            "preview": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And expecting output of Aggregation as below:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Level 1",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "Horizontal zero administration moratorium",
        "lectures": [
          {
            "title": "Balanced exuding adapter",
            "content": "758050245",
            "preview": true
          },
          {
            "title": "Versatile mission-critical forecast",
            "content": "**000**",
            "preview": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Level 2",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "Inverse systemic solution",
        "lectures": [
          {
            "title": "Phased executive function",
            "content": "**000**",
            "preview": false
          },
          {
            "title": "Stand-alone object-oriented intranet",
            "content": "758050248",
            "preview": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You can use the aggregation `$map` operator - it allows iterating the elements of an array field and _transforming_ the elements. I think you can specify a condition for changing specific elements. That said, you can also, nest the `$map` operators.

Comment: Thanks prasad. You are right looks like $map is the one that I can use. I am trying to use it with conditions and also in nested array.